# push properties in array from dropdown and input - Angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, input

I have row of input fields and dropdowns. I can generate new row by clicking on button "Add row". I managed via "i of index" to get values for every input in that row, but I am unable to do that for dropdowns (also i get error when i select item from dropdown). When you fill inputs and select from dropdowns you can see result in console log after pressing button.

Plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uKmRu185YD4RwrUcwBW9?p=preview)

console.log example:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

0
:
{name: "A", data: "123", num: "", char: ""}
1
:
{name: "B", data: "123", num: "", char: ""}

Perhaps  there is some other solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use the ng model property on it ?
**[Something like in this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hjTIYMV0TkMRZXp3U6h4?p=preview)**

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="this.properties[i].num">
  <option selected disabled>Select type</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of numberTypes">{{type}}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="this.properties[i].char">
  <option selected disabled>Select type</option>
  <option *ngFor="let type of charTypes">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sure... any minute, there is time limit ;)

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that !